# Why is this strange character included in emails sent from cakePHP running on my Ubuntu server?

Tags: email, cakephp, character-encoding, html-email

I am seeing some strange characters appearing in emails that are sent out form my CakePHP app running on an ubuntu server.

The characters are -

D with stroke through it - Đ - this appears where I am including a cakephp variable
O with tilde - Õ - instead of apostrophe
E with accute - É - instead of ... (3 dots)

Any idea why they would be appearing? The O with tilde appears in place of apostrophes so I assume its a character encoding issue..

I am using Cake to send html emails.

any leads appreciated
thanks

Comment: what encoding are you using

Comment: This is from my app/config/core.php file - Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');  I also added this line to show the £ symbol correctly when using money_format - $locale_setting = 'en_GB.utf8'; - i add this line on any page that uses money_format (probably not the right way to do it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

1) in config/core.php search this `App.encoding`, the line should look like this `Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');`, set it to `UTF-8` if it is not.

2) In your layout, in the head section add this,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

3) Change your entire project's encoding to `UTF-8` in your IDE(if you are using Zend Studio, just right click on the project and select 'properties', then select UTF-8 encoding).

Though sending email has nothing to do with database(of course if are you not fetching some data from there for sending), but you could perhaps add `'encoding' => 'utf8'` line in your `database.php` file under `$default` configuration, to not have any encoding issues saving in db.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks - number 1 was set but in the default layout the charset was set to iso-8859-1 so have updates this to utf-8. hope this fixes it! thanks for your reply